# Camel REST and Spring Security Java Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, apache-camel

I'm trying to set up Camel REST to use basic auth with a simple username/password from my application.properties and can't for the life of me seem to configure Camel Spring Security to do that.  I'm trying to follow [the Spring Security component documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/others/spring-security.html#SpringSecurity-Authentication) which seems to be missing the example of configuring the required beans.  I found the missing example [here](https://help.talend.com/reader/SUzvVjxkFWs4p6BXVXwyHQ/V7Yb1Lz1cLSaAC_dnLkrMw) under 'Controlling access to Camel routes' but this only shows the xml configuration.

How do I set up the required `SpringSecurityAuthorizationPolicy` bean? It needs an `AuthenticationManager` and an `AccessDecisionManager` and it also seems to require that I set its `SpringSecurityAccessPolicy` which I have no idea how to do.

I haven't gotten to test these yet, because I can't get my beans set up, but my rest route looks like:

```
rest("/ingest")
            .post("/json").consumes("application/json")
            .route()
            .process(authProcessor)
            .policy(authPolicy) // this is the bean I don't know how to configure
            .to("direct:ingest")
            .endRest();
```

and my AuthProcessor (taken from the camel component doc) looks like:

```
@Component
public class AuthProcessor implements Processor {

    public void process(Exchange exchange) {
        String userpass = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(exchange.getIn().getHeader("Authorization", String.class)));
        String[] tokens = userpass.split(":");

        // create an Authentication object
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(tokens[0], tokens[1]);

        // wrap it in a Subject
        Subject subject = new Subject();
        subject.getPrincipals().add(authToken);

        // place the Subject in the In message
        exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.AUTHENTICATION, subject);
    }
}
```

and here's my broken bean configuration for what it's worth:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public SpringSecurityAuthorizationPolicy springSecurityAuthorizationPolicy(
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager) {
    SpringSecurityAuthorizationPolicy policy = new SpringSecurityAuthorizationPolicy();

    SpringSecurityAccessPolicy springSecurityAccessPolicy = new SpringSecurityAccessPolicy();

    policy.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    policy.setAccessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager);
    policy.setSpringSecurityAccessPolicy(????);

    return policy;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("pass").roles("USER");
}

@Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
public AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
    AffirmativeBased affirmativeBased = new AffirmativeBased(ImmutableList.of(
            new RoleVoter()
    ));

    affirmativeBased.setAllowIfAllAbstainDecisions(true);

    return affirmativeBased;
}
}
```

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to understand this so an example of how to do this would be amazing.  It looks like the xml configuration for what I want to do (in the second link) is simple enough but I can't seem to replicate it in Java configuration.

Comment: At this point I'm wondering if I should even bother with trying to use Spring security and whether I should just break up the Authorization header and throw an exception if it doesn't match the user name and properties in my config.  Seems like a hack but pursuing this further feels ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old topic, but I ran into similar questions. I managed to get it working. Not by overriding the `accessDecisionManager()` method within the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class, but by constructing a new instance while building my `SpringSecurityAuthorizationPolicy`:

```java
@Bean
public Policy adminPolicy(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    RoleVoter roleVoter = new RoleVoter();
    SpringSecurityAuthorizationPolicy policy = new SpringSecurityAuthorizationPolicy();
    policy.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    policy.setAccessDecisionManager(new UnanimousBased(List.of(roleVoter)));
    policy.setSpringSecurityAccessPolicy(new SpringSecurityAccessPolicy(roleVoter.getRolePrefix() + "<ROLE_NAME>");
    return policy;
}
```